# NFC communication - Mifare Desfire AES - change key command

Tags: key, aes, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I'm using a HID Omnikey 5321 reader to communicate with Mifare DESFire EV1 tag. I'using WinSCard DLL (in C++) to wrap Native DESFire Command in ISO 7816 APDU message structure. On the tag, I have an application with 3 keys. As the Key Settings are set to 0x0B, I authenticate with application master key to change keys values.

I manage to change application master key but not key 1 and 2.

After AES authentication with application master key, I try to change key 2 :

```
Old Key 2 = 00...00
New Key 2 = 22...22
```

I calculate CRC over (Old Key 2) XOR (New Key 2)

```
CRCxor = F1 4A D1 C0
```

I calculate CRC over Native Command

```
Native Command = C4 02 (New Key 2)
CRCnc = C9 1F 03 80
```

Then I encipher with the session key and IV set to 00

```
32 bytes data to encipher : (New Key 2 XOR Old Key 2) (CRCxor) (CRCnc) 00...00
```

APDU sended

```
90 C4 00 00 21 02 (enciphered data) 00
```

In response I get "1E" status code which mean CRC or padding error.

I also try without XORing data. I just append CRC calculated over Native Command, like I did to successfully change Master key, but I still have the same error.

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but if your application code is written in Python, make sure you are using lists and bytearrays consistently. You might not be passing the data you think you are to your PCD.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).